# AngularJS Scope watch to find which binded attribute changed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am writing a program in which I watch an array inside of my scope. `Scope.watch` works as needed, which gives me the modified value. But, how do I find out which element has been changed?

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    myarray[i] = "var_" + i;
}

Scope.$watch(myarray[i], function (newValue,OldValue) {
    alert(myarray[i]); // Doesn't give me the correct value changed attributes because i has been modified
});
```

How can I known which attributes have been changed, for example: var_1, var_2?

Comment: compare `newValue` to `oldValue`

Comment: I want to know which attribute has changed ... not the changed value (which I get it correctly) . Please read the questions

Comment: the question was read, you need to loop through properties and compare

Comment: Not sure why -1 was given. Can you please provide the code for the property change "Please read : Scope.watch works properly which gives me the changed value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for this `$scope.$$watcher` contain all the attribute for which the  scope is watching . Iterating the $$watcher and checking the last value on it (`$watch.last`) and then you have name of the attribute in eval .So comparing the newvalue with the $watch.last attribute and fetching the name of the attribute from watch do the trick.

I will soon edit this answer with the example  : [Code](http://nirajkr.com/angularjs/angularjs-trick-to-watch-changed-variable-in-a-scope/)

Answer (score 2):

If your code really looks like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    myarray[i] = "var_" + i;
}

Scope.$watch(myarray[i], function (newValue,OldValue) {
    alert(myarray[i])
}
```

Then the answer is simple. Your watch will always trigger when `var_4` changes.

Why is that?

It's because you're creating the watch outside of the scope of the `for` loop. Because of the way variable scoping works in JavaScript, the loop variable is scoped to the function, so your code still works, but doesn't do what you would expect -- the value of `i` in `Scope.$watch(myarray[i], ...)` will be the last value from the loop.

If you want to specify the scope variables to watch within a loop, you'd do something like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    myarray[i] = "var_" + i;

    Scope.$watch(myarray[i], function (varName) { 
        return function (newValue,OldValue) {
            alert(varName + "changed, new value: " + newValue);
        }
    }("var_" + i));
}
```

This will create a new watch for each loop iteration, and passing the variable name through the intermediate function scope will ensure that it will be the correct one.

Having said all that, I'm fairly sure that you're *doing it wrong* if you find yourself needing to create watches in a loop. If you were to explain what you are trying to accomplish, we might be able to provide an answer that makes more sense. For instance, if you want to watch scope variables var_1 and var_2, you could simply:

```
Scope.$watch("var_1", function (newValue,OldValue) {
    alert("var_1 changed: " + myarray[i])
}

Scope.$watch("var_2", function (newValue,OldValue) {
    alert("var_2 changed: " + myarray[i])
}
```

If you need to observe changes to an array of arbitrary length and know the changed index, you can try this:

```
function firstDifferetIndex(a1, a2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        if (a1[i] != a2[i]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

Scope.$watchCollection("[" + myarray.join(",") + "]" , function (new, old) {
    var changedIndex = firstDifferentIndex(new, old);
    alert("var_" + changedIndex + " changed");
});
```

I'm still fairly sure this is not what you want to actually do, but given the amount of information we've got on the problem, this is the best I can do. But I'm guessing you might want to combine `ng-repeat` with a custom directive to get what you want in a cleaner way.

Comment: I have 4-5 attributes all are text values . I want to know which attributes has changed . Inside the watch I do get the correct changed value but I am not sure which attribute has changed out of 5.

Comment: Why not simply explicitly set a watch for each attribute you want to observe?

Comment: because those will be set dynamically and may be 40-50 attributes

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hack: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k664m8rc/5/)

```
scope.myArray = [];

for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    scope.myArray[i] = { text: "var_" + i, id: i };

    scope.$watch("myArray." + i, function (new, old) {
        console.log("Changed Variable", scope.myArray[new.id].text);
        console.log("Index", old.id); // Or new.id as long as you don't modify them.
    }, true);
}
```

So, if you need to find out which element is changed, use `old.id` or `new.id`.